# Showing White Screen in Flutter Project

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

After running my project, a white screen appeared without any errors.

```dart
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations(
      [DeviceOrientation.portraitUp, DeviceOrientation.portraitDown]);

  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  static const appName = 'Marc Jr Foundation';
  //https://upcdatabase.org/
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      child: Provider<AuthBase>(
        create: (context) => Auth(),
        child: MaterialApp(
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Add properly formatted & only required part where it is throwing error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inorder to use `MultiProvider`, you need to provide `providers`.

```dart
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  static const appName = 'Marc Jr Foundation';
  //https://upcdatabase.org/
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        Provider(
          create: (context) => AuthBase(),
        )
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        theme: ThemeData(
```

Answer (score 1):

In terminal use;

1. `flutter clean`
2. `flutter pub get`